# create multiple excel files with the data in dataframe using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a sample dataframe1

```
City         Employee     Manager          email                date
Florida city    XYZ          ABC       abc@example.com       2021-03-01
Huston          XYZ          ABC       abc@example.com       2021-03-02
Miami city      MNO          ABC       abc@example.com       2021-03-01
Washington DC   KLM          XYZ       xyz@example.com       2021-03-01
Pittsburg       EFG          XYZ       xyz@example.com       2021-03-01
California      HIJ          XYZ       xyz@example.com       2021-03-01
```

How do I iterate through the manager column in such a way that rows/data of one manager should be saved in excel and the rows/data of another manager should be saved in another excel?

desired result

first excel data (filename: ABC - XYZ, MNO)

```
  city       | employee   |     manager   |    email           |       date
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
Florida city |   XYZ      |    ABC        |  abc@example.com   |    2021-03-01
Huston       |   XYZ      |    ABC        |  abc@example.com   |    2021-03-02
Miami city   |   MNO      |    ABC        |  abc@example.com   |    2021-03-01
```

second excel data (filename: XYZ - KLM, EFG, HIJ)

```
    city      |  employee  |  manager  |   email            |       date
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Washington DC |  KLM       |   XYZ     |  xyz@example.com   |    2021-03-01
Pittsburg     |  EFG       |   XYZ     |  xyz@example.com   |    2021-03-01
California    |  HIJ       |   XYZ     |  xyz@example.com   |    2021-03-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this can be pretty straightforward with `groupby`:

```
#Import
import pandas as pd

# Set your path
path = r'G:\xxx\xxx'

# Groupby 'manager' column and export different csv's with names in manager
for x,y in df.groupby('Manager'):
    y.to_excel(f'{path}\{x}.xlsx', index = False)
```

This will save in your path all the different `xlsx` files named with the unique values in your manager column, structured like:

```
# File 1

ABC

           City Employee Manager            email       date
0  Florida city      XYZ     ABC  abc@example.com 2021-03-01
1        Huston      XYZ     ABC  abc@example.com 2021-03-02
2    Miami city      MNO     ABC  abc@example.com 2021-03-01

# File 2
XYZ

            City Employee Manager            email       date
3  Washington DC      KLM     XYZ  xyz@example.com 2021-03-01
4      Pittsburg      EFG     XYZ  xyz@example.com 2021-03-01
5     California      HIJ     XYZ  xyz@example.com 2021-03-01
```